# Portable/fast way to obtain a pointer to Numpy/Numpypy data

Tags: python, api, numpy, ctypes, pypy

I recently tried `PyPy` and was intrigued by the approach. I have lots of C extensions for Python, which all use `PyArray_DATA()` to obtain a pointer to the data sections of `numpy` arrays. Unfortunately, PyPy doesn't appear to export an equivalent for their `numpypy` arrays in their `cpyext` module, so I tried following the recommendation on their website to use `ctypes`. This pushes the task of obtaining the pointer to the Python level.

There appear to be two ways:

```
import ctypes as C
p_t = C.POINTER(C.c_double)

def get_ptr_ctypes(x):
    return x.ctypes.data_as(p_t)

def get_ptr_array(x):
    return C.cast(x.__array_interface__['data'][0], p_t)
```

Only the second one works on PyPy, so for compatibility the choice is clear. For CPython, both are slow as hell and a complete bottleneck for my application! Is there a fast and portable way of obtaining this pointer? Or is there an equivalent of `PyArray_DATA()` for PyPy (possibly undocumented)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still haven't found an entirely satisfactory solution, but nevertheless there is something one can do to obtain the pointer with a lot less overhead in CPython. First off, the reason why both ways mentioned above are so slow is that both `.ctypes` and `.__array_interface__` are on-demand attributes, which are set by `array_ctypes_get()` and `array_interface_get()` in `numpy/numpy/core/src/multiarray/getset.c`. The first imports ctypes and creates a `numpy.core._internal._ctypes` instance, while the second one creates a new dictionary and populates it with lots of unnecessary stuff in addition to the data pointer.

There is nothing one can do on the Python level about this overhead, but one can write a micro-module on the C-level that bypasses most of the overhead:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

PyObject *_get_ptr(PyObject *self, PyObject *obj) {
    return PyLong_FromVoidPtr(PyArray_DATA(obj));
}

static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"_get_ptr", _get_ptr, METH_O, "Wrapper to PyArray_DATA()"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initaccel(void) {
    Py_InitModule("accel", methods);
}
```

Compile as usual as an Extension in `setup.py`, and import as

```
try:
    from accel import _get_ptr
    def get_ptr(x):
        return C.cast(_get_ptr(x), p_t)
except ImportError:
    get_ptr = get_ptr_array
```

On PyPy, `from accel import _get_ptr` will fail and `get_ptr` will fall back to `get_ptr_array`, which works with Numpypy.

As far as performance goes, for light-weight C function calls, `ctypes + accel._get_ptr()` is still quite a bit slower than the native CPython extension, which has essentially no overhead. It is of course much faster than `get_ptr_ctypes()` and `get_ptr_array()` above, so that the overhead may become insignificant for medium-weight C function calls.

One has gained compatibility with PyPy, although I have to say that after spending quite a bit of time trying to evaluate PyPy for my scientific computation applications, I don't see a future for it as long as they (quite stubbornly) refuse to support the full CPython API.

**Update**

I found that `ctypes.cast()` was now becoming the bottleneck after introducing `accel._get_ptr()`. One can get rid of the casts by declaring all pointers in the interface as `ctypes.c_void_p`. This is what I ended up with:

```
def get_ptr_ctypes2(x):
    return x.ctypes._data

def get_ptr_array(x):
    return x.__array_interface__['data'][0]

try:
    from accel import _get_ptr as get_ptr
except ImportError:
    get_ptr = get_ptr_array
```

Here, `get_ptr_ctypes2()` avoids the cast by accessing the hidden `ndarray.ctypes._data` attribute directly. Here are some timing results for calling heavy-weight and light-weight C functions from Python:

```
                             heavy C (few calls)      light C (many calls)
ctypes + get_ptr_ctypes():         0.71 s                   15.40 s
ctypes + get_ptr_ctypes2():        0.68 s                   13.30 s
ctypes + get_ptr_array():          0.65 s                   11.50 s
ctypes + accel._get_ptr():         0.63 s                    9.47 s

native CPython:                    0.62 s                    8.54 s
Cython (no decorators):            0.64 s                    9.96 s
```

So, with `accel._get_ptr()` and no `ctypes.cast()`s, ctypes' speed is actually competitive with a native CPython extension. So I just have to wait until someone rewrites `h5py`, `matplotlib` and `scipy` with ctypes to be able to try PyPy for anything serious...

Answer (score 0):

That might not be answer enough, but hopefully a good hint. I am using scipy.weave.inline() in some parts of my code. I do not know much about the speed of the interface itself, because the function I execute is quite heavy and relies on a few pointers/arrays only, but it seems fast to me. Maybe you can get some inspiration from the scipy.weave code, particularly from `attempt_function_call`

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/weave/inline_tools.py#L390

If you want to have a look at the C++ code that is generated by scipy.weave,

1. produce a simple example from here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/weave.html ,
2. run the python script
3. get the scipy.weave cache folder:

   ```
   import scipy.weave.catalog as ctl
   ctl.default_dir()
   Out[5]: '/home/user/.python27_compiled'
   ```
4. have a look at the generated C++ code in the folder

Comment: Unfortunately, `scipy.weave` does nothing else than generating C code using the CPython API (`#include <Python.h>`), which is not going to work with `PyPy`. Within the CPython API, `PyArray_DATA()` is the most effective way to get a pointer to the data section of numpy arrays, but it is not portable to PyPy.